# location.href and location.replace not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to redirect the user from one page to another and it works fine in every browser except IE.

I have some menu-options and for some reason, making the links basic like this `<a class="d-block" href="/customer/search-and-filter/nav-funds#category=1,2" id="fundsSwedenAndNorth">` doesn't work in any browser. Therefore I had to make click events on those links and I made them like this:

```
$('#fundsSwedenAndNorth').on('click', function(){
    location.href = '/customer/search-and-filter/nav-funds#category=1,2';
});
```

It worked fine in every browser except IE where the page reloads but doesn't redirect to where I want it to go, it just stays on the same page. I also tried with `window.location.replace('/customer/search-and-filter/nav-funds#category=1,2');` instead of location.href and this didn't work either.

Comment: Any messages in the console?

Comment: @RamprasathSelvam that is invalid syntax - location.reload(boolean) is to reload current page

Comment: *"is this messing it up"* - well the simple test is to comment out that code and see if it's still messed up.  Only take a couple of seconds to do and you'll answer yourself.

Comment: If you have `<a href='url#hash'` and you're already on `url` then it won't "redirect"/"reload" and will jump to that anchor.

Comment: Also `location.href = location.href + '/' + this.getAttribute("href").substring(1);` will fail to load any other page  if the location.href has a hash

Comment: @SadhanaDhande that is not the problem.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55862692/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide relevant HTML and script in a [mcve]. My strong guess is that you already have a # in the location and then you try to add `"/"+this.getAttribute("href").substring(1);` to it

Comment: People was focusing on the wrong thing so I edited my question. There are no messages in the console. The previous "/"+this.getAttribute("href").substring(1); was not the problem cause i had an if/else-statement that worked fine preventing your suggestions that it fails. Also the code does not switch anchor between links. For example i have http://myurl.com/search-and-filter/nav-funds#category=1 and the next link ends in #category=2, but it doesn't switch to that, which is why I had to do click events.

Answer (score 0):

It is so strange that location.href and location.replace not working in IE.

I've made several tests and thay all work well in IE.

It would be a bit tough to determine exactly what is going wrong with your existing code as it should be working just fine.

My suggestion is that maybe you could debugger in your js code in IE to see if it is correct.

```
$('#fundsSwedenAndNorth').on('click', function(){
   debugger;
   location.href = 'link';
});
```

Besides, maybe you could try Document​.location():https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to invalid characters or having some space between them. Give a try by using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). I hope it helps.